# psql command "Error: PostgreSQL version 12 is not installed"

Tags: postgresql

I have installed PostgreSQL 11 but for some reason when I type `psql` in the terminal I get `PostgreSQL version 12 is not installed` error

Recently I uninstalled a PostgreSQL server so I think I didn't do it well

How could I get psql command exec version 11 instead of 12

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I've reproduced your case and here's how I resolved it:

Use `sudo apt purge postgresql-12` answering `Yes` if you want to remove it completely:

```
  ┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤ Configuring postgresql-11 ├────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
  │                                                                                                                                                                    │ 
  │ Removing the PostgreSQL server package will leave existing database clusters intact, i.e. their configuration, data, and log directories will not be removed. On   │ 
  │ purging the package, the directories can optionally be removed.                                                                                                    │ 
  │                                                                                                                                                                    │ 
  │ Remove PostgreSQL directories when package is purged?                                                                                                              │ 
  │                                                                                                                                                                    │ 
  │                                                  <Yes>                                                     <No>                                                    │ 
  │                                                                                                                                                                    │ 
  └────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

After this:

```
sudo psql --version
psql (PostgreSQL) 11.7 (Ubuntu 11.7-2.pgdg19.10+1)
```

Comment: That's it, Thank you

Comment: This seems to be generally valid. I first installed `postgresql-12` and then updated to `postgresql-13`, but it was still using the `pg_dump` from `postgresql-12` (so was refusing to dump reload to my `postgresql-13` cluster). Purging 12 worked here also.

Answer (score 3):

I had installed `postgresql-13` then "rolled back" to `postgresql-client-12` after an OS upgrade.  I found a zombie `/etc/postgresql/13` directory and removed it and I can now successfully execute `psql`

Answer (score 1):

Just move the `/etc/postgresql/12` directory somewhere else and only leave the version that `pg_dump` is installed on that directory.

I found it out by issuing `strace  pg_dump|& grep open` command

Answer (score 0):

The problem is actually being caused by a postgresql port mapping issue in the config files.

By default, Kali comes with postgres 12 (and postgres 13 as of 2020.3), but OpenVAS needs version 13. Kali configures postgres 12 to port 5532 and  assigns a higher port (in this case, 5433) for postgres 13. OpenVAS is still looking for 5432 so sees postgres 12 even if 13 is installed.

remove postgresql 12 if you can...if not

A quick solution is to edit the "port = " lines in the

/etc/postgresql/12/main/postgresql.conf
port = 5433

and

/etc/postgresql/13/main/postgresql.conf
port = 5432

basically swap the port values.